# Retornando somente o maior valor de uma lista Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho a lista `['4', '07', '08', '2017', '364', '355673087875675']` e gostaria de re uma fórmula para retornar o maior valor, que neste caso seria o `'355673087875675'`, tentei usar o `max()`, mas não funcionou , não estou conseguindo pensar em uma solução simples para este problema, estou pensando em usar um algoritmo de classificação mas ficaria muito grande o código, deve ter alguma maneira da fazer isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use o int como função de ordenação para a função max

```
>>> l = ['4', '07', '08', '2017', '364', '355673087875675']
>>> max(l, key=int)
'355673087875675'
```

Comment: ola consegui aqui muito obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Tem. Utilizar a própria função `max`. O problema pelo qual não funcionou seu código é porque você possui uma lista de *strings* e quer avaliá-las como valores inteiros, então precisa da conversão.

```
numbers = ['4', '07', '08', '2017', '364', '355673087875675']

print(max(int(number) for number in numbers))  # 355673087875675
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/rUXDXx) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/InfamousSkinnyYellowjacket)</sup>

Ou seja, ao invés de aplicar `max` direto na lista, precisa aplicá-la em uma lista cujo todos os valores foram devidamente convertidos para inteiro.

Answer (score 3):

Já está bem respondido e eu usaria a função [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), mas para uma pessoa que está aprendendo poderia querer ver como achar o máximo, ainda que a performance seja menor e por isso não deveria ser usada em outros cenários.

Essencialmente faça o que a função faz. Você pode fazer um laço analisando cada um dos itens. Começa com o menor valor possível de Python como sendo seu primeiro máximo, e claro este valor é negativo. Então sempre que achar um valor maior que o máximo atual você muda o máximo para esse novo valor. Só não haverá uma mudança de valor se não tiver itens na lista ou se o único valor existente seja o menos valor possível em Python (`-inf`).

```
lista = ['4', '07', '08', '2017', '364', '355673087875675']
max = float('-inf')
for item in lista:
    item = int(item)
    if item > max:
        max = item
print(max)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MLJQTg). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/lbtonboptv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/MaxList.py).

Ele não identifica um erro se a lista estiver vazia. Não é difícil verificar antes se a lista tem algum valor e pode melhorar este código. O problema é que pode ter um valor mas não ter um valor válido, isso já precisa ser tratado olhando cada item pra ver se tem pelo menos um valor válido, isso depende de mais um `if` dentro do laço e uma variável de controle para saber se achou um deles.

Se a lista fosse `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` os códigos de todas as respostas dariam erro. Não tem como resolver usando `max()` puro, com o `for` só depende de mudar o algoritmo para ver se tem pelo menos um valor válido ou dar erro se existir um valor inválido, o que é até bem mais fácil fazer, só depende entender qual é o objetivo para escolher o melhor caminho. Exemplo que parece maior, mas é mais robusto, se o objetivo for este:

```
def maximum(lista): 
    max = float('-inf')
    for item in lista:
        try:
            valor = int(item)
            if valor > max:
                max = valor
        except:
            pass
    return max

print(maximum(['4', '07', '08', '2017', '364', '355673087875675']))
print(maximum(['4', '07', '08', '355673087875675', 'a', '2017']))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Jq4fRo). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/dktxgjivst-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/MaxList2.py).

Se você quiser que dê um erro mais específico em vez de dar um resultado só com o que é válido, aí fica com você, mas a ideia é só mudar o `pass` para um erro.